# Is it necessary to unsubscribe events for items in an ObservableCollection in case a new collection as been assigned?

Tags: c#, events

As far as I know (and as is stated in many posts here on SO) you should always unsubscribe from events in order to avoid a leak. However I was wondering about the following case:

```
ObservableCollection<myClass> myCollection = new ObservableCollection();

// add items....

foreach(var item in myCollection)
{
   item.somePropertyChanged += OnSomethingChanged;
}

// work with the collection...

// new we just assign a new collection to the existing collection
myCollection = new ObservableCollection<myClass>(someNewListOfMyClass);
```

Do I have to unsubscribe to all the deleted items manually, or does the GC collect them without unsubscribing in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The items are *not* deleted (at least not immediatly).
You don't know *when* GC will finally delete all those items (and it will only do so if there are no other references left somewhere else).

And as long as these items exist in memory, they may raise their events and execute your `OnSomethingChanged` handler.

However, subscribing to `item.SomePropertyChanged` does not generate a reference to `item` that will keep GC from destroying it. It rather creates a reference to your instance that declares `OnSomethingChanged`.

Comment: OK, but will the GC delete them in the first place IF there are still events subscribed to them?
Edit: thx for the clarification!

Comment: @RolandDeschain No, subscribing to an event of `item` does not create a reference to `item` but to the class/instance declaring the handler. Added it to my answer.